# Universal App not updating GUI when appending control in runtime

Tags: c#, xaml, async-await, win-universal-app

I'm making some kind of splash window for long lasting operations. The code of control is:

```
public sealed partial class WaitingArea : UserControl
{
    private Page ParentPage = null;
    private Grid ParentGrid = null;

    public WaitingArea(Page Parent, int Width, int Height, string Text)
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        this.ParentPage = Parent;
        this.ParentGrid = Support.FindVisualChildren<Grid>(ParentPage).First();
        this.Width = Width;
        this.Height = Height;

        messageArea.Text = Text;

        ParentGrid.Children.Add(this);
        ParentPage.IsHitTestVisible = false;
    }

    public static async Task<WaitingArea> Show(Page Parent, int Width, int Height, string Text)
    {
        return new WaitingArea(Parent, Width, Height, Text);
    }
}
```

Now, when I'm calling it like this:

```
private async Task Foo()
{
    await WaitingArea.Show(this, 300, 150, "please wait");
    await Foo2(); //-> this actually calls C++ code "Sleep(5000);"
}
```

The splash form occurs only after `Foo2()` method executed. Why is so? How to force form to show up right at the `WaitingArea.Show` call?

Comment: You are using WPF? I think you need to use a dispatcher for these GUI operations.

Comment: How do you actually add the WaitingArea control to the page? Is this done in the constructor?

Comment: @SebastianR, I've updated code, but does it matter how?

Comment: @Marius, I've tried to call this code via "Windows.ApplicationModel.Core.CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync" method - same result. Did you mean something else?

Comment: I'm guessing if you replace `Foo2` with `await Task.Delay(5000);` it works?

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer, yes. But the point is to use native C++ code in the project - so I'm emulating it with Sleep operation.

Comment: @AlekDepler, if you are using WPF, there is something like `Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke()`

Comment: @Marius, it is Windows Phone 8.1 application, I cant find "Application.Current.Dispatcher", it's only available "Windows.ApplicationModel.Core.CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher" and there is no "BeginInvoke" method, only "Ru‌​nAsync" (which I think is pretty much the same thing)

Comment: Try running Foo2() in a background worker thread (Task.Run(() => Foo2())) and await this.

Comment: @SebastianR, hm it's working... But I'm still angry and don't understand what is going on.

Comment: @AlekDepler Have a look at Manfred's answer. The problem is that C++'s Sleep(5000) is executed on the UI thread, but need's to be on a different thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your `Foo2` method is most likely not a "real" `async` method, but just some busy background task. The WPF Layouting Cycle needs some time too, and since your `ParentGrid` doesn't just redraw instantly (like in the good ol' times) but invokes `InvalidateLayout` and `InvalidateMeasure`, it takes some time for your control to actually show up.

In your case your `async Foo2` operation takes up all (or most of) the time that would otherwise be used to update the UI.

Simply putting the `async` keyword in front of everything doesn't make it magically execute in a background thread without noticeable UI impact. In your case the easiest solution might be to wrap Foo2 in a `Task.Factory.StartNew` or `Task.Run`

Comment: Yes, wrapping in Task.Run is working. Is there any other approaches to do this, maybe with callbacks as JavaScript style?

Comment: Absolutely, I'd recommend using a background worker or thread (depending on what exactly you are doing in Foo2). But that might rather be a topic for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/). Opionion-based questions don't survive long on StackOverflow since they are considered off-topic.